# Ember - Pikaday format displaying incorrect date

Tags: ember.js, datepicker, pikaday

Using Pikaday as a date picker within my form with the format set to DD/MM/YYYY. For some reason, I keep on getting a 'too much recursion' error when I select the textfield and the date appears incorrectly after I've selected different dates.

If I set the format to 'MM/DD/YYYY' then it works without any errors but when I set the format to 'DD/MM/YYYY', I come across issues.

I have created a JSBin to demonstrate my problem: http://jsbin.com/nuxasipedi/1/edit

After further testing, it looks as though having the date in the UK format with slashes confuses the plugin.

Comment: Your jsbin does not seem to work with either format...

Comment: Also, have you seen this? https://github.com/Frozenfire92/ember-pikaday

Comment: I've updated the jsbin so it shows the format at MM/DD/YYYY without any errors. When the format is now changed to 13th Aug for example, the incorrect date is displayed. I've just tried using ember-pikaday and I get the same issue.